How to Use Stateful Fuzzing in Foundry to Verify Conditions for Emitting Events?
I have a contract in which I am emitting an event when a certain condition is met
enum Type {
  One,
  Two
}

function _someFunc() internal {
  ...
  if (someVar != 0) {
    emit Abstain(Type.One)
  }
}

function _someFunc2() internal {
  ...
  if (someVar == 0) {
    emit Abstain(Type.Two)
  }
}

Here if the condition is met, it emits the event.
What I want to test is that whenever Abstain is emitted with enum Type.One someVar is always not zero and since the function are internal and are being called by several other functions i'd like to use stateful fuzzing to so i can see if there is any code path that nullifies this condition.
